# addEventListener for array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, addeventlistener

With this code I'm trying to iterate over a Array which is derived from a json Array.
There is a SVG inside the page. 
When I click on a country, the name should be submitted to a URL.
Unfortunately I get the following error at the line indicated with -->error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null**

How can I overcome this error?? And why is it occurring?

The array is like this:

```
{"Countries":["india","switzerland","usa","alaska","germany","austria","netherlands","france","italy","spain","poland","hungary","czech","romania","russia","china","mexico","brazil","britain","thailand","sweden","uae","new_zealand_north_island","new_zealand_south_island","egypt"]}




var mySVG = document.getElementById("VectorMap");
var svgDoc;
mySVG.addEventListener("load", function () {
    svgDoc = mySVG.contentDocument;

    $.getJSON("http://www.someurl.com/jsonArray",
        function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {

              var i=0;
              for (tot=item.length; i < tot; i++) {
                var someElement = svgDoc.getElementById(item[i]);
                 //--->error
                 someElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
                     $("#info").html(ajax_load).load("http://www.someurl.com/returnData"+"?country="+text);

                 }, false);    //add behaviour
              }

            });
        });
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking whether the element exists before attempting to attach the event handler; if the element doesn't exist, `getElementById()` would return `null`. This code would have that check.

```
var someElement;

for (var i = 0, tot = item.length; i < tot; i++) {
    someElement = svgDoc.getElementById(item[i]);

    if (someElement) {
        someElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
           $("#info")
              .html(ajax_load)
              .load("http://www.someurl.com/returnData"+"?country="+text);    
        }, false);    //add behaviour
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is happening because in the page there is no element with the `id` given. In such case, `getElementById` returns `null`: you can check by your web console / debugger in the browser, what is this `id` that doesn't exists, and if it is supposed to be there – and therefore you have an error or typo.

Anyway, you could take advantages of jQuery. Because in jQuery you can pass a list of ids, and the listener will be attached only to those elements that are actually in the page, without throwing exception. So in your case, instead of:

```
var i=0;
for (tot=item.length; i < tot; i++) {
  var someElement = svgDoc.getElementById(item[i]);
   //--->error
   someElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
       $("#info").html(ajax_load).load("http://www.someurl.com/returnData"+"?country="+text);

   }, false);    //add behaviour
}
```

You can simply have:

```
$('#' + item.join(', #')).on('mousedown', function() {
   $("#info").html(ajax_load).load("http://www.someurl.com/returnData"+"?country="+text);
});
```

So basically, assuming `item` is an array (and therefore I would call it `items`) with plain ids, like `['a', 'b', 'c']`, with `'#' + item.join(', #')` you will obtain `"#a, #b, #c"` as string to pass to jQuery: if any on those elements doesn't exists in the page, the mousedown listener simply won't be attached, without raise any error.

Note: not sure where this `text` variable came from, I just put there because in your original example.